# in HorizontalListview setSelection has no effect

Tags: android, listview

in HorizontalListview,i want to locate to the middle item,for example,the 15th item in a 30size list view , here comes the question.
When i called setSelection() after setAdapter() is had no effect,what's the reason?

`adapter = new HorizontalListViewAdapter();
horizontalListView.setAdapter(adapter);
horizontalListView.setSelection(orderTime.size() / 2);`

Comment: What HorizontalListView do you use?

Comment: If the one by Paul Soucy setSelection is not implemented there.

Comment: MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView, this is what i use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such as you are using OpenSoruce `HorizontalListView` which is modified version of [Paul Saucey `HorizontalListView`](https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android) , you can open code and see that setSelection method does nothing with scroll. I've worked with HorizontalListView library and performed some modifications which you can find [here](https://gist.github.com/httpdispatch/8953995). For your purpose use the method `scrollToIndex`

Comment: Thanks for your reply,i had found the reason,the HoriziontalListview is extends the AdapterView instead of AbsListview so the setSelection() method is not implemented.you are right.